# Flask Application returning ImportError: No module named user_auth.views

Tags: python-2.7, flask, importerror

I'm in the beginning stages of a Flask application. The problems I'm having is that whenever I attempt to run the application I get:

```
app/application/___init___.py, line 11 in <module>
from user_auth.views import auth
ImportError: No module named user_auth.views
```

I have no idea what the problem is. The import for the home.view did this as well, then it stopped and worked fine on the local server. Been trying to figure this out for the longest, there aren't that many moving parts in the application as of yet, so not sure why this is happeninng. File structure and code below:

|app
|-application
|--__ init __.py
|--home
|--user_auth
|----forms.py
|----views.py
|----templates
|----static

My application/__ init __.py file:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object('_config')

from home.views import home
from user_auth.views import auth

app.register_blueprint(home)
app.register_blueprint(auth)
```

My application/user_auth/views.py

```
from flask import Blueprint


auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__, 
                    url_prefix='/user_auth',
                    template_folder='templates', 
                    static_folder='static')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `__init__.py` file under ./user_auth/ to make `user_auth` a module.

There's more information about modules [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).